What is the best way, today, to update disk or SSD firmware on Ubuntu?
Quite everything is in the question title...
Lastly, I "upgraded" a PC my wife use to SSD disks, adding more memory. As this PC had a Windows 10 disk which was not booted since ages (2017 comes to mind...) I relentlessly removed the disk holding it.
The only use for this Windows was to use the main-board BIOS update tool and firmware update tools for various hardware.
So my question : If such update arose, how would I do it using Ubuntu ? I ask because I've found various answer none of which seems current.
Thanks a lot for your answer and have a nice week-end !
Edit : I forgot to add that I use Ubuntu Noble 24.04.1 LTS . Sorry.

Use your Ubuntu product to update firmware.  You've not provided any product/release details; as doing it varies on Ubuntu product/release; but on my release I'd use the firmware-updater provided by the system, which is a snap package on my system. On other systems it's provided as a deb package; but use whatever is appropriate for your unstated Ubuntu OS.

Hello Guiverc, I also hafe a snap "firmware-updater" installed. No manual page, no help available and if you click on "check firmware" button, the little Ubuntu logo spins and spins and spins...

You can check firmware versions: Firmware versions
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version &
udisksctl status Older hardware will not be in fwupdate. Devices using LVFS for firmware updates
https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist My Desktop stopped having UEFI firmware updates after about 3 years. For my SSD, I was able to download update ISO directly from their support page. Probably varies by vendor, but I found My Dell laptop &  Samsung  NVMe to be very good on updates. More info https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd

Ah OldFred ! You where lucky !
For my SAMSUNG MZALQ256HAJD-000L2 I can't find any information neither on the laptop maker website nor at Samsung ! So if you have a link, I would be delighted  !
Have a nice day ;-)
